# C# Class Not CLS-Compliant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just wondering why the following class declaration underlines the variable name (with a green squiggly mark) and says the following:

**Type of MyClass is not CLS-Compliant.**

**CustModel.cs**

```
public class CustModel
{
  Public List<MyClass> ListOfMyClass { get; set; }
}
```

**MyClass.cs**

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int field1 { get; set; }
  public string desc { get; set; }
  public string title { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the CustModel as a return object in my MVC view (i.e.):

```
public ActionResult MyStuff()
{
  List<MyClass> lst = GetSomethingList();
  CustModel mdl = new CustModel();
  mdl.ListOfMyClass = lst;

  return this.View(mdl);
}
```

I am not getting an error, but I just want to understand why it is not CLS compliant and at the same time, whether this is a good implementation?

Comment: Perhaps its the lowercase field names which don't comply to the usual naming convention.

Comment: The `public` key word is in lower case, so you first snippet wouldn't even compile. ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos CLS doesn't require a specific casing - in fact it is case-insensetive.  The requirement is that you can't have two classes/members that differ _only_ by different casing.  (e.g. `name` and `Name`)

Comment: Are these classes defined in the same assembly?

Answer (score 1):

You would get that message if the class is not in an assembly with a `[assembly:System.CLSCompliantAttribute(true)]` defined for it.

Answer (score 1):

If the classes are defined in different assemblies, make sure that both assemblies are decorated with `[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]` (or at least, that both assemblies are consistent).

> An assembly that is not marked as CLS-compliant is considered to be
>   not CLS compliant.

If `MyClass` is in an assembly that is not decorated as CLS compliant, but `CustModel` (because it has a public property that uses `MyClass`) is marked CLS compliant, you will get a compiler warning.

Further reading:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.clscompliantattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.100).aspx